# How do I bind an array of parameters to a MySQLi statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a website in php that uses a MySQL database. I'm programming database function calls using MySQLi. I want to write a generic function to handle the preparation of a mysql statement. Here is non-working code:

```
<?php

function execute_statement($mysql, $statement, $typeDef = FALSE, $params = FALSE){
    if(($stmt = $mysql->prepare($statement))){

        if($typeDef){
            // bind params
            $stmt->bind_param($typeDef, $params);
        }

        // store result
        $stmt->store_result();

        // execute the statement
        $stmt->execute();

        // close statement
        $stmt->close();

        // return result
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function add_event($mysql, $eventTitle, $eventDescription)
{
    // execute statement
    if(!execute_statement($mysql, "INSERT INTO events "
            . "(title, "
            . "description) "
            . "VALUES(?, ?)",
            "ss",
            array(&$eventTitle, &$eventDescription))){
        $error = "Database error";
        $details = "Failed to add an event to the database";
        return json_encode(
                array(
                    "result"=>false, 
                    "error"=>$error, 
                    "details"=>$details,
                    "params"=>array(
                        "title"=> $title,
                        "description"=>$desc)));
    }
}

?>
```

The execute_statement method is used for 'insert' statements only. How do I bind my array of parameters to the statement?

Comment: Are you asking about `$params` and how to `foreach` over it? You know this has been solved a million times over. (And would be redundant if you'd not be using the awful mysqli functions, but just PDO like everyone else.)

Comment: @mario i'm new to website development. i just read some about pdo and prepared statements seem to be easier to handle. thanks for adviced